# External CA configuration with puppet agent

Tags: ssl, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am trying to configure the puppetserver and agent to use external CA with - Root self-signed CA & Master,Agent having its own ssl certificate

**Configurations in puppetserver:**

/etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/bootstrap.cfg

```
# To enable the CA service, leave the following line uncommented
# puppetlabs.services.ca.certificate-authority-service/certificate-authority-service
# To disable the CA service, comment out the above line and uncomment the line below
puppetlabs.services.ca.certificate-authority-disabled-service/certificate-authority-disabled-service
```

/etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/conf.d/webserver.conf

```
ssl-cert    : /usr/cachelogic/var/device-pki/dev_cert.pem
ssl-key     : /usr/cachelogic/var/device-pki/dev_key.pem
ssl-ca-cert : /usr/cachelogic/var/device-pki/CAcert.pem
ssl-crl-path : /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/crl.pem
```

puppetserver service was started successfully.

**Configurations in puppet agent:**

/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf

```
hostcert = /usr/cachelogic/var/device-pki/dev_cert.pem 
hostprivkey = /usr/cachelogic/var/device-pki/dev_key.pem 
localcacert = /usr/cachelogic/var/device-pki/CAcert.pem
```

While starting the puppet agent following this the error message that I get.

```
Debug: Using cached certificate for ca
Debug: Creating new connection for https://cp3.zzz152d1.cdn:8140
Debug: Using cached certificate for ca
Error: Could not run: stack level too deep
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:63
```

Any pointers on debugging this issue will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, if you are doing something like an external CA, then your company probably needs Puppet Enterprise. That contract includes support for stuff like this.

Comment: Can you post a trace? (--trace option)

Comment: Using --trace gives a extra line `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:63` which I have already updated.